# how to retrieve Apache ignite cached Cassandra table in sorted format in JAVA?

Tags: ignite

I am using spring-boot code for loading data from Cassandra table called "test". I have defined group index and mentioned the order of persistence but when I am trying to get all records using "findAll()" method the data is not coming in a sorted way.
please let me know am I going in a wrong way. Because I am not sure how to retrieve cache table data in a sorted way.

cassandra table:

```
create table test(key int primary key, city text, location text, subscribers int);
```

java object:

```
public class Test {

    @QuerySqlField(orderedGroups = { @QuerySqlField.Group(name = "city_subscriber_location", order = 0) })
    String city;
    @QuerySqlField(orderedGroups = {
            @QuerySqlField.Group(name = "city_subscriber_location", order = 1, descending = true) })
    int subscribers;
    @QuerySqlField(orderedGroups = { @QuerySqlField.Group(name = "city_subscriber_location", order = 2) })
    String location;
}
```

xml file:

```
<persistence keyspace="ignite" table="test" ttl="86400">
    <keyspaceOptions>
        REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1}
        AND DURABLE_WRITES = true
    </keyspaceOptions>
    <tableOption>
        comment = 'Cache test'
        AND read_repair_chance = 0.2
    </tableOption>
    <keyPersistence class="java.lang.Integer" strategy="PRIMITIVE" column="key"/>
    <valuePersistence class="com.cache.business.model.Test" strategy="POJO"/>
</persistence>
```

configuration:

```
public Ignite igniteInstance() {
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("ignite-1");
    cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
    cfg.setMetricsLogFrequency(0);

    DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();

    dataSource.setContactPoints(environment.getProperty("cassandra.contact-points"));
    RoundRobinPolicy robinPolicy = new RoundRobinPolicy();
    dataSource.setLoadBalancingPolicy(robinPolicy);
    dataSource.setReadConsistency("ONE");
    dataSource.setWriteConsistency("ONE");

    CacheConfiguration<Integer, Test> ccfg2 = new CacheConfiguration<>("test");// table name
    ccfg2.setIndexedTypes(Integer.class, Test.class);
    //ccfg2.setWriteBehindEnabled(true);
    ccfg2.setReadThrough(true);
    ccfg2.setWriteThrough(true);

    CassandraCacheStoreFactory<Integer, Test> f2 = new CassandraCacheStoreFactory<>();
    f2.setDataSource(dataSource);

    KeyValuePersistenceSettings persistenceSettings = new KeyValuePersistenceSettings(
            new ClassPathResource("test.xml"));// corresponding xml file

    f2.setPersistenceSettings(persistenceSettings);

    ccfg2.setCacheStoreFactory(f2);

    cfg.setCacheConfiguration(ccfg, ccfg2);

    /**
     * Start Ignite server and load cache for all the cache configurations
     */
    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);

    IgniteCache<Integer, Test> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("test");

    cache.loadCache(null);

    return ignite;
}
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "city": "mumbai",
    "subscribers": 986,
    "location": "marthalli"
  },
  {
    "city": "mumbai",
    "subscribers": 427,
    "location": "centra"
  },
  {
    "city": "mumbai",
    "subscribers": 739,
    "location": "krmarket"
  },
  {
    "city": "hyd",
    "subscribers": 637,
    "location": "krmarket"
  },
  {
    "city": "bgr",
    "subscribers": 575,
    "location": "krpuram"
  }
```

I am not getting output in sorted format. please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we shouldn't use findAll method of ignite repository.

use below way to query

```
@Query("SELECT subscribers FROM test where city = ?")
    List<Integer> selectAll(String city);
```